# How to cancel TableAdapter.Update()

Tags: transactions, dataset, tableadapter

How can one cancel an already running `TableAdapter.Update()` call? I'm calling it inside an `SqlTransaction` and can therefore easily call `Rollback()` on the transaction, but that doesn't stop the execution of Update() itself.

Note: I'm running `Update()` on a BackgroundWorker in case you're wondering how do I call `Rollback()` during another executing function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this by using the `TableAdapter.Update(DataRow r)` overload and sending it one row at a time. This way if I need to cancel the operation at some point, I can simply break the loop and roll back my transaction. Easy, isn't it?!